# ShowController with TabbedShowLayout

Tags: react-admin

I am actually doing a dashboard using React-Admin, and I discovered the `<ShowController>` who permits to use Material-UI components inside the Show View.

But my problem comes here, I used a `<TabbedShowLayout>` and it doesn't work really well. Let me explain :

```
<ShowController {...props}>
    {controllerProps =>
      <ShowView {...props} {...controllerProps}>
        <TabbedShowLayout {...controllerProps}>
          <Tab icon={<AssignIcon />}>
            <div>
              <TextField source="id" />
            </div>
          </Tab>
        </TabbedShowLayout>
      </ShowView>
    }
</ShowController>
```

Here is my actual code, and it displays nothing except the tab with the icon.
But if i remove the `<div>` component, it works.

I would like to know, if someone ever does that, and made it works.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is properties inheritance is not "native", you have to do it manually. react-admin is doing it in each component.

When you insert a `div` element in a react-admin form or layout, you break this inheritance between `Tab` and `TextField`. The `div` is receiving `props` from parent `Tab`, but doesn't forward them to `TextField`.

One solution is to make a custom wrapper. In your case:

```
<ShowController {...props}>
    {controllerProps =>
      <ShowView {...props} {...controllerProps}>
        <TabbedShowLayout {...controllerProps}>
          <Tab icon={<AssignIcon />}>
            <CustomDiv>
              <TextField source="id" />
            </CusomDiv>
          </Tab>
        </TabbedShowLayout>
      </ShowView>
    }
</ShowController>
```

With

```
const CustomDiv = ({children, ...props}) => (
    <div>
        {
            React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {...props, ...child.props}))
        }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helps me a lot to understand.